# CakePHP strange cache problem _t_t_t

Tags: php, cakephp

Appears when I upload my site to the server the cache behaves strangely and names my cached elements with _t_t_t. Anyone had a similar problem?

Local
element_cache_site_tweets
Server:
element_cache_t_t_t

Answer (score 0):

You should check function which creates the cache in you app and put `var_dump($key); exit;` just before the actual cache key is set.

This does not seems to be server issue, You might be passing some variable weirdly.